# bash / zsh protractor: auto run protractor's CLI commands in --elementExplorer mode

Tags: javascript, bash, protractor, zsh

how it possible to write a bash script that run Protractor and send some init commands to it, like :
*"prx.sh"*

```
protractor --elementExplorer
browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
```

look simple, but Protractor block the second command by it internal loop
we can do:

```
protractor --elementExplorer &
```

but then we need some way to send the next command to protractor SDIN

e.g
I know I can use :

```
protractor --baseUrl 'http://www.angularjs.org'  --elementExplorer
```

to solve above example, but I'm interested in general how to run environement command for init some variables, so it will be more easy to  play with them in the interactive mode

I thinks it is general qustions about bash\zsh

Comment: Just to clarify: After the init commands have been entered, should `protractor` wait for further user input? Maybe [this questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103885/piping-data-to-a-processs-stdin-without-causing-eof-afterward) has some helpful answers.

Comment: right, inject some init command and wait for further input